# How to divide two columns in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am retrieving each ID's rows per page with no problem. I have two columns in the DB's table which is extend and price. I want to use divide math on these columns value. My retrieving code is right below. I also want to add this code a divide math! `extend / price`

```
public function show($id)
{
    $estates = allestates::where('id', $id)->first();

    return view('pages.show', ['estates' => $estates]);
}
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: please explain your question a bit more briefly to be understandable.

Comment: `$estates->extend / $estates->price` should do it. A slightly more convenient way would be to create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators). Also, `$estates` is a little misleading, since you only get one item (`->first()`)

Comment: @kerbholz no problem with the code, with that code I am retrieving ID's data per page. I also do some math with specific columns.

Comment: @BonishKoirala question updated.

Comment: @Potti: Means you need this result(i.e $rsltDivide = extend / price;) in view file?

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal yes that's very right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $estates = allestates::where('id', $id)->first();

    $rsltActualPrice = $estates->extend / $estates->price;

    return view('pages.show', compact('estates','rsltActualPrice'));
}
```

Put `$rsltActualPrice` this variable in view file like:

```
{{$rsltActualPrice}}
```

**OR**

change your view file code like:

```
{{$estates->extend / $estates->price}}
```

**Updated Answer**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $estates = allestates::where('id', $id)->first();

print('<pre style="color:red;">');
print_r($estates);
print('</pre>');
exit;

$rsltActualPrice = $estates->extend / $estates->price;

return view('pages.show', compact('estates','rsltActualPrice'));
```

}

Comment: I tried second option because I thought it's simple way but. `{{$estates->extend / $estates->price}}` but I got this error. `A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/pages/show.blade.php)`

Comment: and I tried to use function too but got this error: `A non well formed numeric value encountered`

Comment: @Potti: Please show your result (i.e print('<pre style="color:red;">');
    print_r($estates);
    print('</pre>');
    exit;)

Comment: The "easy" way to debug in Laravel is using `dd()`: `dd($estates)`

Comment: @Potti: Please check may be anyone value is not numeric may be it's string value pass so please check both values (i.e extend field value and price field value) are numeric or not

Comment: @SaurabhDhariwal I have lots of rows and some of those doesn't have number? if it's the problem then how can I overcome this?

Comment: @Potti: So please show result (i.e print_r($estates);)

Comment: I am sorry but, where am i going to use that print_r ? in blade or controller?

Comment: wait i am updating my answer with print_r()

Comment: @Potti: Please check my updated answer and show result

Comment: and also add like this: $rsltActualPrice = (int) $estates->extend / (int) $estates->price;

Comment: okay! @JinalSomaiya that solved the problem! thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Going the `accessor` way. In your model, create a method

```
public function getActualPriceAttribute()
{
    return $this->extend / $this->price;
}
```

Your model now has a "virtual" attribute `actualPrice` that you can call, for example in a blade file:

`{{ $estates->actual_price }}`

More on accessors: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

On a sidenote: `$estates = allestates::where('id', $id)->first();` can be shortened to `$estates = allestates::find($id);`

Comment: it returns this error mate; `A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/pages/show.blade.php)`

Comment: You need to make sure your values are actually divisible. All the answers/suggestions here assume they already are.

Comment: thank you for help. I think the problem is: i have lots of rows and some those has not number but string. But how can I overcome this problem? I just want to division which rows has numbers

Comment: Sounds like a database "issue". Make sure there are only "number" values in those fields. The field in your database should not be string if you want to do math with them. Probably worth a new question